# Email validation + disable button

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, email

so i've done some code for contact form, but i have some problems to finish it up. So here is part of html contact form

```
<form action="" method="POST" name="contact-form" id="contact-us" >
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="fullname" class="name send-check" placeholder="Name" tabindex="1" />
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="name send-check" id="email" placeholder="Email" tabindex="2" />
                        <div class="msg success error"> Incorrect e-mail </div>
                        <textarea rows="10" cols="45" name="msg" placeholder="Message" class="name send-check" tabindex="3"></textarea>
                        <a id="go" name="logo_order" href="#logo_order" rel="leanModal" disabled><button type="submit" id="btn-send" value="Отправить" disabled>Отправить</button>
                        <div id="logo_order">
                            Thank you for your message, window will close after 5 seconds.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

When you type first time incorrect email at field (Email) it will write you with red color "Incorrect email", so then you re-write to your correct email and after that if you delete your correct email and type random letters it wil validate(it shouldn't) and disable button will become enabled, and also after that you click send, the modal appears and all form fields clears and enabled button becomes disable, but after that you type again in all three fields random text, the button will be enabled, so it's not doing validation at e-mail input

**External code** before /body to disable button, after click on Send

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#btn-send').click(function () {
   $('#contact-us').trigger("reset");
   $('button:submit').attr("disabled", true);
 });
});
</script>
```

**Internal code**

Validation

```
$('form input[name="email"]').blur(function () {
    var email = $(this).val();
    var valid = /(.+)@(.+)\.(com|edu|org|etc)$/;
    if (valid.test(email)) {
        $('.msg').fadeOut(500);
        $('.success').fadeOut(500);
        $(".send-check").each(function () {
            $(this).keyup(function () {
                $('#btn-send').prop('disabled', checkinput());
            });
        });
    } else {
        $('.error').fadeIn(500);
    }
});

function checkinput() {
    var valid = false;
    $(".send-check").each(function () {
        if (valid) { return valid; }
        var input = $.trim($(this).val());
        valid = !input;
    });
    return valid;
}
```

leanModal v1.1 | Ray Stone | Licensed under the MIT and GPL

```
(function($){$.fn.extend({leanModal:function(options){var defaults={top:100,overlay:0.5,closeButton:null};var overlay=$("<div id='lean_overlay'></div>");$("body").append(overlay);options=$.extend(defaults,options);return this.each(function(){var o=options;$(this).click(function(e){var modal_id=$(this).attr("href");$("#lean_overlay").click(function(){close_modal(modal_id)});$(o.closeButton).click(function(){close_modal(modal_id)});var modal_height=$(modal_id).outerHeight();var modal_width=$(modal_id).outerWidth();
$("#lean_overlay").css({"display":"block",opacity:0});$("#lean_overlay").fadeTo(200,o.overlay);$(modal_id).css({"display":"block","position":"fixed","opacity":0,"z-index":11000,"left":50+"%","margin-left":-(modal_width/2)+"px","top":o.top+"px"});$(modal_id).fadeTo(200,1);e.preventDefault()})});function close_modal(modal_id){$("#lean_overlay").fadeOut(200);$(modal_id).css({"display":"none"})}}})})(jQuery);
```

Timeout-modal

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#go').click(function (e) {
        $('#logo_order, #lean_overlay').fadeIn(400, function() {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#logo_order, #lean_overlay').fadeOut(400);
            }, 5000);
        });
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        $('#logo_order, #lean_overlay').fadeOut(400);
    });
});
```

Comment: Remove ALL JavaScript/jQuery. `<input type="email" />` is *all you need*.

Comment: yeah, but it is HTML5, i have tried to make js code for fallback :)

Comment: You shouldn't need it. Obviously it's causing more trouble than it's worth. Either way, validation should be server-side.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol thank your for your help :) Appreciate that!